# swift, how i find the letter that i want in sentence or word?

Tags: swift, indexing

I want to find letter in variable a,
what is code for searching method?

Example:

```
 var a = ["coffee","juice","water"]
```

search letters is "co"

searching method's result is "cofee",

what is searching method?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read  How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to iterate over an array and select elements which match some condition, there's a `filter` method for that. In this case you need to check if a word contains some string, so use `containsString`.

```
a.filter { $0.containsString("un") }
```

Comment: sorry, i rewrite my question